# Dynamic feature file passing in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I want to pass Feature File name dynamically in 'Features' field in below annotation of Cucumber

```
@CucumberOptions(
  dryRun = false,
  strict = true,
  features = {
    "src/com/Proj/Feature/Dashboard.feature"
  },
  glue = "com/Proj/StepDefinition",
  tags = {},
  monochrome = true,
  plugin = { 
    "pretty",
    "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
    "json:target/cucumber.json" 
  }
)
```

Currently before running we have to pass feature file, do not want to hard code Dashboard.feature feature file

Comment: can you provide some of your configuration or code on this context?

Answer (score 1):

By default, you will pass `.feature` file in runtime only.

**To run particular feature file**

```
> cucumber feature_file_name.feature
```

**To run particular Scenario**

> cucumber feature_file_name.feature:(line no. of scenario)

```
> cucumber feature_file_name.feature:10
```

**To run entire feature file in project**

```
> cucumber
```